# How to run command every 15min?

Tags: command-line

I want to run a command every 15min. Here is the command I want to run:

```
sudo bash -c "sleep 1h; pm-suspend"
```

Answer (score 6):

I am unable to comment due to insufficient reputation however @Edwin Hernandez crontab example of `*/15, *, *, *, * sudo bash -c "sleep 1h; pm-suspend"` is incorrect as there should not be commas between the fields (each of the stars are a separate field).  @Mitch♦ has the correct format.

`cron`'s format is:

```
m h dom mon dow command
```

m is the minute, h is the hour, dom is day of month, mon is the month, and dow is day of week.

In your comment you ask a supplementary question about running every day and every week.

`14 04 * * * command` is every day at 04:14am

`39 06 * * 3 command` is every Wednesday at 6:39am (0 = Sun, 1 = Mon, etc...)

`39 06 * * wed command` as previous line

**Caution #1:**  If you use `* * * * wed command` then it will run every minute of every hour every Wednesday.  If you only want it to run once a day then you need to specify the minutes and hours of the day you want it to run. I've been bitten by this on more than one occasion. It can be very frustrating.

**Caution #2:**  If the command you want to run is the `pm-suspend` command then I would suggest that you look at all crontab files for all users to find a suitable time after they have finished processing any commands you feel are important.  e.g. if you are running a backup starting at 05:44 and then set your `pm-suspend` to run at 05:50 there is a possibility that the backup will not have finished before suspending which is probably not a helpful state of affairs.

The reason that the "random" times are used in the example is that crontabs often set off their commands at these "random" times to spread the load so that a lot of processes are not all starting at once

It should be noted that any output of cron is emailed to the user if email is set up.  You will not see any output on the screen/terminal.

**An aside**

If you ever need to watch something change over a shorter time frame (the default is 2 secs) then `watch` is a useful command.  Finding this command was a godsend!

**Other reading**

On SO [How can I make a bash command run periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394356/how-can-i-make-a-bash-command-run-periodically) has lots of links in that might help explain things in alternative ways.

Or if you can cope with the somewhat meaty `man` pages:

`man 8 cron`

`man 1 crontab`

`man 5 crontab`

Answer (score 2):

A step by step guide would be like:

1. Editing your crontab: type in a terminal:

   ```
   $ crontab -e
   ```
2. Add the following line to it.

   ```
   */15 * * * * sudo bash -c "sleep 1h; pm-suspend"
   ```
3. Save and quit: type `:wq` and then press `enter` if you are on vi.

Comment: am want run command every days and every weeks ..etc Please Help me more . and how to Save !?

Comment: It's better to use `sudo crontab -e` instead of having sudo in the cron job command. As the other will need to wait for the password input. But even better is to use `contab -e -u <some-user-name>` if it is an option.

Comment: @ManNewInUbuntu Refer to this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Predefined_scheduling_definitions) for customized scheduling definitions.

Comment: and [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/vi/three.html) to see how to save in the vi editor.

Comment: I don't see how that could work, using `sudo` in crontab. Where should the password come from?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to run a [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) command every 15 minutes. Like this, where each minute is specified:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'cron'. [Official instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto). There is a complimentary `anacron` daemon too, that allows to create rules like `5 minutes after connecting to Internet`

Answer (score 0):

you could try it using `while` loop, save the following code in a file and run it as `sudo bash <filename>`. you have to run it once, it will run in terminal as long as you dont cancel it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo bash -c "sleep 1h; pm-suspend"
```